# Scraping webpage elements with VBA script

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

With some help I've put together a macro to scrape webpage elements by tag ID from URLs (indicated in column A of an Excel sheet) and insert the text into columns B, C and D. The code loops from 1st row until 1000th. So far so good.

The problem is that it seems to be taking SOOOO much time. Is there any way to speed up the process? I feel like my use of IE pages isn't optimal.

(Please note that I'm aware that `On Error` the code is copying previous data as new but I have a manual easy work around to clean the data, which works fine until I get around to fixing that issue.)

```
Sub getCountry()
'
' GetCountry Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+k
'
  Dim IE      As Object: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  Dim ws      As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Dim Country As String
  Dim Category As String
  Dim Network As String
  Dim n As Integer
  n = 729
  For n = 729 To 1000
    With IE
    Visible = False
    .navigate ws.Range("A" & n).Value
    Do
      DoEvents
        Loop Until .readyState = 4
      End With
      On Error Resume Next
      Country = Trim$(IE.document.getElementByID("youtube-user-page-country").innerText)
      On Error Resume Next
      Category = Trim$(IE.document.getElementByID("youtube-user-page-channeltype").innerText)
      On Error Resume Next
      Network = Trim$(IE.document.getElementByID("youtube-user-page-network").innerText)
      ws.Range("B" & n).Value2 = Country
      ws.Range("C" & n).Value2 = Category
      ws.Range("D" & n).Value2 = Network
    Next n
  IE.Quit
  End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you did this in VBA, instead of scraping it with a more specialized tool and export to CSV (which Excel can import perfectly fine)?

Comment: Probably because of a lack of knowledge and a strong like for excel. No knowledge of any tool specialized in scraping a long list of varying URLs but I'm open to suggestions.

For the edit, I don't get the edit of the title, I thought phrasing it in a question was recommended.

Thanks for the feedback and time !

Comment: As for the edit, no, the current title is more appropriate. See [this meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2438/52915) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The indentation is terribly misleading.

Compare yours:

> ```
>   For n = 729 To 1000
>     With IE
>     Visible = False
>     .navigate ws.Range("A" & n).Value
>     Do
>       DoEvents
>         Loop Until .readyState = 4
>       End With
> ```

To how [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com)'s *Smart Indenter* default settings do it:

```
For n = 729 To 1000
    With IE
        Visible = False
        .navigate ws.Range("A" & n).Value
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until .readyState = 4
    End With
```

If I glance at your code, I've no idea where the `With` block ends, and at second glance it appears to end in the middle of a `Do` loop body (which would be illegal) - it takes a third read to pick up the matching `Loop` keyword hidden in the code.

Before modifying anything, fix the indentation.

Running Rubberduck inspections reveal that variable `Visible` is never declared, which means `Option Explicit` isn't specified at the top of the module, which means VBA will happily compile typos, and that can easily lead to very hard-to-debug problems. **ALWAYS** specify `Option Explicit`, and declare **all** variables.

The macro is *implicitly* `Public`, `n` should probably be declared `As Long`, and the procedure name should be `PascalCase`, i.e. `GetCountry`, although the name suggests it's *getting* some value, which usually implies a `Function` that *returns* that value - `Sub` procedures *do* something, they don't *get* stuff.

`On Error Resume Next` will make your macro keep running in error state, which makes the assignments fail and, as you noted, the previous iteration's value gets repeated. Why not "reset" the 3 values at the end of each iteration? That way a failed `getElementByID` would write an empty string instead of duplicating data. That said...

> ```
>     On Error Resume Next
>     Country = Trim$(IE.document.getElementByID("youtube-user-page-country").innerText)
>     On Error Resume Next
>     Category = Trim$(IE.document.getElementByID("youtube-user-page-channeltype").innerText)
>     On Error Resume Next
>     Network = Trim$(IE.document.getElementByID("youtube-user-page-network").innerText)
> ```

Error handling doesn't work that way; only the first OERN changes anything, the other two are perfectly redundant. If you want to *restore* error handling you need to do `On Error GoTo 0`:

```
    On Error Resume Next 'suppresses run-time errors
    Country = Trim$(IE.document.getElementByID("youtube-user-page-country").innerText)
    Category = Trim$(IE.document.getElementByID("youtube-user-page-channeltype").innerText)
    Network = Trim$(IE.document.getElementByID("youtube-user-page-network").innerText)
    Err.Clear 'clears error state
    On Error GoTo 0 'restores run-time errors
```

As for speeding things up, assuming lightning-speed scraping this would be the bottleneck:

> ```
>     ws.Range("B" & n).Value2 = Country
>     ws.Range("C" & n).Value2 = Category
>     ws.Range("D" & n).Value2 = Network
> ```

You know how many iterations you're making, therefore you know from the start how many rows you're going to be writing to the worksheet; the fastest way to write to a worksheet isn't one cell at a time.

Declare a 2D array, populate it in your loop, and dump the array onto the worksheet to perform all `Range` writes in one single, instantaneous operation. Otherwise you're having Excel raise `Worksheet.Change` events, repainting itself, and possibly re-calculating things *every time you write to a cell*.

You could "cheat" and do `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the top and set it back to `True` at the end of the procedure, but that wouldn't be any more efficient code. Go with the 2D array.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with scraping in browser is this: along with the data (the only thing you need = HTML), the browser displays everything (HTML, CSS, JS) and renders it (even more time wasted).

The best solution for non interactive scraping is to use HTTPRequest, get only HTML as response. This way you are working with HTML DOM without rendering overhead.

Storing and writing the data in excel should be done in Mat's way, store all on 2D array, write once into sheet. Writing one cell at a time is brutally inefficient.